# Have thick bottom borders depending on If statement using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel with columns C:W. I’m trying to create a way such that if a row in column D contains a 1, then columns C:W of that row will automatically have a thick bottom border. I’ve realized that conditional formatting cannot solve this problem, however I understand a solution to this problem might be possible by VBA. Any assistance about how I would go about doing this in VBA would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you found in your research? Have you tried using the macro recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've mentioned Conditional Formatting, you're looking to get something applied "automatically". And you can't use LineStyles as there's not a predefined type for thick border. One option is to add code to the Worksheet_Change event which reads through your range something like this (simplistic) example which assumes the data is in the range C1:W10 ...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim vSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vRow As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set vSheet = Target.Worksheet
    For Each vRow In vSheet.Range("C1:W10").Rows
        If vRow.Cells(1, 1) = 1 Then
            vRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = 3
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```